# Java threads executing then being interupted multiple times

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a strange issue where I have a thread being used to listen for incoming messages on a socket. The thread is declared globally but instantiated inside method listen(). This allows me to interrupt it from another method stopListen() which works perfectly the first time, however when listen() and stopListen() are called a second time it does not appear to get interrupted. The code commented as "Do some stuff" still executes after waiting for the incoming message the second time. Below is a cut down version of the code.

```
public class Con {
    private Thread listen;

    public void listen() {
        listen = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    //Wait for an incoming message
                    if (!Thread.interrupted()){
                        //Do some stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        listen.start();
    }

    public void stopListen() {
        listen.interrupt();
    }
}
```

I understand its a bit weird having a variable and a method called the same thing. Should this work or can I not interrupt threads by using a global variable more than once?

Thanks.

Comment: How many times do you call `listen()`? Each call will start a new thread. Post the code that uses the classes.

Comment: listen() is called when the application loads. Then I have a JDialog that calls stopListen() in its constructor and listen in its closing method
'this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                con.listen();
            }
        });'

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting on the comment above, my first post on stackoverflow. Just to clarify though, there is only ever one JDialog open and want this thread to be interrupted when it is.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem I see is that [`interrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29) will reset the interrupt-flag (see linked doc), meaning the next call to `interrupted()` will return false unless it has been interrupted again. Instead, use `isInterrupted()` which does not clear the flag!

Also, as chr said, if you start multiple threads (calling `listen()` multiple times) you will only be able to interrupt the latest one. In that case, make a `List` of Threads and interrupt them all (or only the first one in the list and remove it from the list, or whatever functionality you want).

Comment: Thanks for this. If I were to use 'isInterrupted()' to exit any loops and get to the end of the thread I assume the interrupted flag would be reset for the next time I created a new listen thread?

Comment: @user2297216 Yeah, no worries about that, it's object-specific. You could also use isInterrupted() in the if-clause and interrupted() only in the outer while-loop.